# how to get event type that is fired

Tags: apache-flex, event-handling

I am working on Flex project these days and having java background. In my current task, same pop up is opened when two different types of custom events are being fired and I have to hide a button for one event type. So, how i can get event type.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `Event` class has a property called `type` wich is a `string` stating what kind of event it is.

```
  function eventHandler(event:Event):void { 
      trace(event.type);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..but how can i get this type in my mxml file to hide button as I have seperate actionscript file and mxml file. Also i have eventhandler method in actionscript file.

Comment: What are you trying to do? When do you wan't to hide the button?

Comment: I have a common mxml (popup window) for two custom event types(having two ActionScript event files for both), in this popup I have two buttons 'Select' and 'close'. For one event fired I want to hide 'Select' button and for other I want to show this. Hope I am able to make you clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can get it this way:

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myMethod);

function myMethod(evt){
    trace(evt.type);
}
```